# How do you query data by with multiple conditions or indexes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm trying to design a performant NoSQL schema for my Firebase application, but how would I **query multiple checkpoints which have a unique tag**?

Consider the following rules:

- Tiers can have multiple tags
- Tags can have multiple Checkpoints
- Tag keys (names) are unique for each tier
- Checkpoints can have multiple tags, but only 1 tag per tier

Here's what I have so far:

```
{ 
    "tiers": {
        "1": {
            "web": true,
            "android": true
        },
        "2": {
            "basics": true,
            "angular2": true,
            "aurelia": true
        },
        "3": {
            "basics": true,
            "components": true
        }
    },
    "tags" : {
        "1": {
            "web": {
                "name": "Web Development",
                "children": {
                    "front-end": true,
                    "angular2": true,
                    "aurelia": true
                }
            },
            "android": {
                "name": "Android Development",
                "children": {
                    "front-end": true
                }
            }            
        },
        "2": {
            "front-end": {
                "name": "Basics",
                "parents": {
                    "web": true,
                    "android": true
                },
                "children": {
                    "angular2": true,
                    "aurelia": true,
                    "android-studio": true
                }                
            }                           
        },
        "3": {
            "angular2": {
                "name": "Angular 2.x",
                "parents": {...},
                "children": {...}
            },
            "aurelia": {
                "name": "Aurelia 1.x"
            }   
        }        
    },
    "checkpoints": {
        "<randomKey>" : {
            "name": "Angular 2 Quick Start",
            "tags": {
                "1": "web",
                "2": "front-end",
                "3": "angular2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I can query for all checkpoints under the Tier 1 `web` tag with:

`ref.orderByChild('tags/1').equalTo("web").once('value', snap => console.log(snap.val()));`

but since you can only define one `indexOn` rule, it's not optimized. At least if I can set the `indexOn` rule I can at least filter out most of the checkpoints then filter the rest in my code.

**What can I do to efficiently query my checkpoints based on multiple `tags` AND the `tiers`?**

Eventually I'd need to do a query for `checkpoints` with `"tags": {"1": "web" AND "2": "front-end"}` which I can't for the life of me figure out how to execute efficiently. I was thinking of doing another table with composite keys (e.g. each `tier/tag` contains references to ALL child `checkpoints`), but that would lead to requiring me to add and delete references within each tier.

There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was vastly over complicating the solution - I ended up:

1. Removing `Tier` from the equation all together
2. Adding each checkpoint within each tag it was related to
3. Querying all checkpoints related to each selected tag and removing the ones which did not appear in each tag selected

Here's my new schema:

```
allTags = [
  {"abc": true, "def": true, "hij": true},
  {"abc": true, "def": true}
];

tags: [
  { "0": [
    {"software-development": {name: "Software Development", checkpoints: [ {"abc": true}, {"def": true}, {"hij": true}]}}
  ]},
  {"1": [
    {"web": {name: "Web", checkpoints: [ {"abc": true}, {"def": true}]}},
    {"android": {name: "Android", checkpoints: [{"hij": true}]}}  
  ]}
];

checkpoints: [
  {"abc": { name: "Angular2 Quick Start"}},
  {"def": { name: "Building global directives in Angular2"}},
  {"hij": { name: "Android Quick Start"}},
];
```

Creating a new Checkpoint:

```
public createCheckpoint(tags: any[], checkpoint: any) {
  // push checkpoint
  let checkpointRef = this.firebase.child('test/checkpoints');
  let checkpointKey = checkpointRef.push(checkpoint).key(); // might have to do separate call

  // Add checkpoint under each related tag
  tags.forEach(tag => {
    let tagRef = this.firebase.child('test/tags/' + tag.tier + '/' + tag.key + '/checkpoints/' + checkpointKey);
    tagRef.set(true)
  });
}
```

Retrieving all checkpoints based on selected tags:

```
public getCheckpointss(tags: any[]) {
  // tag.tier, tag.key
  let checkpointKeysToGet: string[] = [];
  tags.forEach(tag => {
    let ref = this.firebase.child('test/tags/' + tag.tier + '/' + tag.key + '/checkpoints');
    ref.once('value', snap => {
      let tagKeys:string[] = this.convertToArray(snap.val());
      if (checkpointKeysToGet.length == 0){
        checkpointKeysToGet = checkpointKeysToGet.concat(tagKeys);
      }
      else {
        checkpointKeysToGet.forEach(existingTagKey => {
          let tagKeysInBothTiers = tagKeys.filter(tagKey => {
            return checkpointKeysToGet.includes(tagKey, 0)
          });
          checkpointKeysToGet = tagKeysInBothTiers;
          console.log(checkpointKeysToGet);
        });

      }
    });
  });
}
```

All valid criticisms are welcome as long as you propose a solution to go along with it :)